Test Angular Input
I want an Angular test that mocks keydown of keys 1 and 2 and then assert that the value of the input is 12
My html:
<input
  id="myInput"
/>

My test:
fit('should update input value on key press', () => {
    const inputDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('#money-input')
    );
    const inputElement = inputDebugElement.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;

    inputElement.value = '';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    const event1 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '1' });
    const event2 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '2' });

    inputElement.dispatchEvent(event1);
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(event2);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(inputElement.value).toBe('12');
  });

The current result of my test:


It feels like you are complicating a test case, you can just set the value and trigger the input event, which simulates the same. if you want typing like, you just need to set the value 1 and 2 twice and emit twice.
it('should update input value on key press', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myInput')).nativeElement;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  input.value = '12';
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(input.value).toBe('12');
});

Stackblitz Demo
